# Laravel - Model::create() works, but is missing attributes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So, I have the following Models:

```
class Recursive extends Model {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  // ...
}

class Place extends Recursive {
   protected $table = 'places';
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id'];
   // ...
}
```

The following code is used to create a new `Place`:

```
$place = Place::create([
  'name' = 'Second',
  'parent_id' => 1
]);
```

This results in the following record in the database:

```
| Actual                    | Expected                  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | name     | parent_id | id | name     | parent_id | 
| 1  | 'Top'    | NULL      | 1  | 'Top'    | NULL      |
| 2  | NULL     | NULL      | 2  | 'Second' | 1         |
```

As you can see, the only value being set is the Auto-incrementing `id` column. The 2 columns I'm trying to create are in the `fillable` array, and the model is created, but it's not associated correctly.

Has anyone come across this issue before? I know I can use another method, such as

```
$place = new Place();
$place->name = 'Second';
$place->parent_id = 1;
$place->save();
```

But this isn't the only spot I'm using this code, and I'd prefer to not lose functionality like this.

Edit: Enabling the query log shows the following for the `create()` call:

```
array (
  'query' => 'insert into `places` () values ()',
  'bindings' => 
  array (
  ),
  'time' => 1.26,
),
```

Further edit: Enable MySQL log has the same output as above. Following Miken32's suggestion of reverting the `extends` to `Model` works as expected:

```
array (
  'query' => 'insert into `places` (`name`, `parent_id`) values (?, ?)',
  'bindings' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Second',
    1 => '1'
  ),
  'time' => 1.21,
),
```

Comment: Why you are creating your create method use direct laravel Model create method

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking... Why am I using `Place::create()`?

Comment: use Model create method why you are creating your own create method in recursive model?

Comment: Please read the full question. I have had this issue with and without my own `create` method. I found a thread that said to add that, and so I did, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you enabled logging on your mysql server? Maybe see what the query looks like?

Comment: @miken32 The query is pretty empty: `insert into places () values ()`, with `bindings => array()`. As suspected, the only insert is the auto-incrementing id column (and I would suspect any default-value enabled columns)

Comment: The [MySQL log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) should give you 3 lines, first is `Prepare` showing the query with placeholders, second is `Execute` showing the query with values filled, and third is `Close stmt`.

Comment: @miken32 Oh sorry, misunderstood; that was Laravel's `DB::enableQueryLog`. 1 second...

Comment: If you try making `Place` extend `Model` directly, does the create method work? Obviously not a good permanent solution if you're repeating code all over the place, but it might be worth trying to see what happens.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, if I extend `Model` and move the functions from `Recursive` into `Place`, it works just fine... Also, ran with `mysql_log`, query is exactly the same; `prepare` and `execute` are same query as logged above, `close` is empty.

Comment: My best guess would be that a method on the `Recursive` class is overwriting one of Laravel's functions unintentionally. Does a [mcve] display the same behaviour?

Comment: @miken32 I'll try removing all functions from `Recursive` (there's only 2, so the fallback listed above isn't the end of the world) and see if that still have the same issue.

Comment: I can't think of any other reason for it not to work: https://implode.io/KWP0GC

Comment: @miken32 Unbelievable... The function that was messing with it was `public function __construct()`, which simply called `parent::_construct()`. Upon removing that from `Recursive.php`, I can insert as expected.

Comment: You mean `parent::__construct()`? Or you were missing an underscore in your code?

Comment: @miken32 yeah, typo; there were 2 `_`'s: `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, the constructor looks like this:

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();
    $this->initializeTraits();
    $this->syncOriginal();
    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

However, you overrode this in your `Recursive` class:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

The attributes were not being passed to the constructor, so it was not able to successfully build the query. You could remove the constructor since it's not doing anything, or use this instead:

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: I was just in the process of making a comment about that omission. I'm a little surprised I didn't get a method override compatibility error, but regardless, thank you for the help!

Comment: Because the parameter is optional in the parent, it's not considered a mismatch to omit it from the child.